# Trick Proof: relation of equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, relations

What is wrong in the following reasoning:

Every symmetric and transitive relation is a relation of equivalence

**Proof:**

$x \sim y \Rightarrow y\sim x$ - becuase of symmetry

$x \sim y \wedge y\sim x \Rightarrow x\sim x$ - because of transitivity

Therefore the relation is reflexive - so it is a relation of equivalence

Comment: Consider the empty relation on $\{a\}$. Or if that’s a bit too outré, consider the relation $\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$ on $\{0,1\}$. Your argument gets you $x\sim x$ **only** if there actually is some $y$ such that $x\sim y$.

Answer (score 2):

This argument assumes that $x$ is related to some $y$, which may not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I would elaborate the last answer. The set of things that particular x can be relative to(and due to symmetry those are relative to x) can be Empty set.  If you write your argument fully mathematically - symmetry: For any(means **if** there is any) x ~ y => y ~ x. As a result, you may not have anything to input in this chain of logic to establish the output,  which is otherwise correct.